# Release an iOS app but not through itunes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ad-hoc-distribution

I was asked to do a recruitment app that will recruit people for the company, so of course it will be free. When I released it, it got rejected for being very basic.

Now the client want to just release it through their site if apple don't want to accept it.

I know how to create the `.ipa` file through adhoc disribution which is what I use to give them copy and test it by putting it on a test site so that they can download it on their iphones.

But this is only for testing purposes, only the phones registered as devices on the dev account can download the file successfully.

So is it possible to release an app that will be used by users successfully without submitting it to apple?

Comment: No, apple designed the releasing of apps to pass through them for inspection for security reasons. Apple wants to make sure that the apps that you make will either make money or make their products more appealing to the public which is why basic applications are not allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With an [Enterprise account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) you can more or less host your own private app store for an unlimited amount of devices and distribute in-house without Apple.
With a Developer account you can run ad-hoc installs via TestFlight or comparable services for up to 100 devices.
The new iTunes TestFlight integration announed at WWDC14 allows for 1000 devices.

The only solution that will look truly professional is the Enterprise App Store and it requires you to have a DUNS and an approval from Apple, but generally with a DUNS you're set. It's $299 instead of $99, but that's not so much money for most companies that have a DUNS. Also you can't use that account for publishing apps to the public App Store.

Comment: The app can only be made available to company employees.

Comment: The Enterprise program will not require you to have it checked by Apple. I have used it succesfully in the past when my client didn't want their app in the AppStore because their competitors would find out about it.

Comment: Two possible problems you'll run into by doing this. 1) There is rumoured to be a soft limit on the number of devices that can install the app with an enterprise cert. I've heard it's about 1000, but that's unconfirmed. I've only ever hit about 200 devices with our enterprise profiles. 2) Releasing an app to the public like this, is a violation of your terms with Apple, and they could terminate your dev accounts.

Comment: I think the app hansn't been installed more than 100 times neither in my case. But I do would like to see some back up for that claim because I would need to inform my client about this limitation.

Answer (score 4):

In general, yes it is possible: you can release an enterprise app outside the app store, provided that your company has the requisite enterprise agreement.

However, this is intended for internal use, and while I haven't read the agreement myself, I believe that distribution to the public at large would likely be in breach.  (EDIT: As Zaph points out, this is in fact explicitly disallowed.)

The situation you're describing would fall outside this.

---

Moreover, from a user experience standpoint, it's unreasonable to expect prospective employees to download an application from outside the app store.

This is not only technically difficult for a lot of people, but it would look incredibly unprofessional, which is the opposite of what you're after in a recruitment app.

Comment: The app can only be made available to company employees.

Comment: @Zaph That's exactly what sapi said... "However, this is intended for internal use"

Comment: @Lyndsey sapi stated: "I **believe** that distribution to the public at large would **likely** be in breach." I stated that it would **not** be allowed.

Comment: You need two developer accounts: one for your enterprise app store and one for the regular app store. So if you want to have both you have to pay for both.

Answer (score 1):

No. Apple restricts the apps available to users only to those on App Store.

(Actually, not 100% true - you could release the app on Cydia and target only jailbroken phones, but I suspect this is not what you mean to do.)

Alternately, make a web application, using JavaScript/HTML/CSS. Anyone can use a web application, it can be installed on the launcher screen, and it does not require App Store, just a web server somewhere. If you need persistence, you might also want to look into manifest files and offline apps. Especially if your app is basic, you can make it look and feel almost as a native app using one of the very nice web frameworks such as jQuery Touch.

However, you might just leave it as a webpage - why would you restrict your recruitment pool only to people willing to install your app?

tl;dr: You can't release an ObjC app except on AppStore.

Comment: I see, I was also thinking of making this a web app before the project came but the client insisted that it should also be in apple. I guess it's partly my fault for not being able to see that this will be rejected. Thank you sir

Comment: What does "in apple" mean? Web applications built for iOS look-and-feel are virtually indistinguishable from native ones (except for speed and access to OS functions).

Answer (score 1):

There are already multiple answers to this question, probably because it is not specific enough.
Let's gather all the information that's necessary here:

1. If you want an app for a company (given that you recruited people through the app, i.e. people who used the app would join the company), you should use the Enterprise Program.
2. If the app is meant for the general public (in this case, possibly, you would like the app as a branding, promoting app for the company), you cannot use the Enterprise account, since it violates Apple's terms. As an example, see this funny case: http://www.imore.com/how-gameboy-emulator-finding-its-way-non-jailbroken-devices
3. AdHoc and TestFlight should not be used for a release app. AdHoc only is meant to be used for testing purposes. Introducing non-developer related devices into your AdHoc profile would mean termination of your dev account (e.g. this aggressive and also funny case: http://www.intomobile.com/2012/07/09/apple-goes-after-sites-selling-activations-ios-6-beta/).

Finally, two interesting notes:

- There is no limit to the number of devices in an Enterprise Program app. It's not 1K, at least the information out there says the opposite (e.g. the case with the link in **1**). The 1k device limit will be for beta testers with TestFlight (according to http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2014/06/testflight/).
- An Enterprise account cannot publish apps to the public on the AppStore (see this FAQ: https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html -if it doesn't work, you can load the cached version from Google, etc.). Thanks to Departamento B for this information I didn't know about.